# scala dataframe filter array of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-2.10, apache-spark-1.6

**Spark 1.6.2** and **Scala 2.10** here.

I want to filter the spark dataframe column with an array of strings.

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "L-00417"), (3, "L-00645"), (4, "L-99999"),(5, "L-00623"))).toDF("c1","c2")
+---+-------+
| c1|     c2|
+---+-------+
|  1|L-00417|
|  3|L-00645|
|  4|L-99999|
|  5|L-00623|
+---+-------+

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "L-1"), (3, "L-2"), (4, "L-3"),(5, "L-00623"))).toDF("c3","c4")

+---+-------+
| c3|     c4|
+---+-------+
|  1|    L-1|
|  3|    L-2|
|  4|    L-3|
|  5|L-00623|
+---+-------+

val c2List = df1.select("c2").as[String].collect()

df2.filter(not($"c4").contains(c2List)).show()`
```

I am getting below error.

> Unsupported literal type class [Ljava.lang.String; [Ljava.lang.String;@5ce1739c

Can anyone please help to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `contains` isn't suitable because you're looking for the opposite relationship - you want to check if `c2List` contains `c4`'s value, and not the other way around.

You can use `isin` for that - which uses "repeated argument" (similar to Java's "varargs") of the values to match, so you'd want to "expand" `c2List` into a repeated argument, which can be done using the `: _*` operator:

```
df2.filter(not($"c4".isin(c2List: _*)))
```

**Alternatively**, with Spark 1.6 you can use an **"left anti join"**, to join the two dataframes and get only values in `df2` that did NOT match values in `df1`:

```
df2.join(df1, $"c2" === $"c4", "leftanti")
```

Unlike the previous, this option is not limited to the case where `df1` is small enough to be collected.

Lastly, if you're using earlier Spark version, you can immitate `leftanti` using a `left` join and a filter:

```
df2.join(df1, $"c2" === $"c4", "left").filter($"c2".isNull).select("c3", "c4")
```

Comment: leftanti i think its not in Spark 1.6.2 version

Comment: df2.filter(not($"c4".isin(c2List: _*))) This worked for small set. Let me check for 1500 values set which I have in c2List actually.

Comment: Hello Tzach, Thanks. First approach worked. `df2.filter(not($"c4".isin(c2List: _*)))`